# Using DLL's in Qt: undefined reference

Tags: qt, dll

I want to use an SDK I got for using a scanner. I'm using Qt 5.3 with MingW32 (on Windows 7).
The very first test I wanted to build should just print the SDK version.
Here is my project file

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = Kojak1
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
KOJAKDIR = "C:/Program Files/Integrated Biometrics/IBScanUltimateSDK_x64"
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += $$KOJAKDIR/Include
SOURCES += main.cpp

LIBS +=-L$$KOJAKDIR/lib/ -lIBScanUltimate
```

and here is the source code

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "stdio.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "IBScanUltimateApi.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

  IBSU_SdkVersion sdk_version;
  IBSU_GetSDKVersion(&sdk_version);
  printf("%s %s",sdk_version.File,sdk_version.Product);
  return a.exec();
}
```

Unforturnately I get the message

```
D:\devt\QTProjects\Kojak1\main.cpp:10: error: undefined reference to `IBSU_GetSDKVersion@4'
```

when trying to compile the program.
My lib directory does contain **IBScanUltimate.lib** and **IBScanUltimate.dll**.

Comment: Dependency Walker tells me that the ordinal of IBSU_GetSDKVersion is 1

Comment: DumpBin says that the ordinal of IBSU_GetSDKVersion is 1, so why is IBSU_GetSDKVersion@4 being reported?

Comment: You said that installed MinGW version of Qt, However `.lib` extensions usually are the extension for `MS COFF` import/static library, used in Visual Studio. Try installing Qt with Visual Studio, or generate an `ELF` import/static library with extension `.a`, used in MinGW, of the desired library. An example here: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/CreateImportLibraries. And please tell us yours results.

Comment: Do not have Qt with Visual Studio, been using Qt5.3.1, don't know where to get the Qt sources. No success with dlltool, but just as bad feel very cramped discussing it here. Even QLibrary does not allow resolving the symbol IBSU_GetSDKVersion although the library seems to load!

Comment: Are you sure to not try to load a 64 bit DLL with a 32 bit application or vice-versa?

Comment: Yes, I think that the installed DLL is a "64 bit" and my MingW32 is .... 32 bits. Doesn't the linker warn about this?

Comment: Now I get fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'X64'. Did I make enough changes by just changing the solution platform to X64?

Comment: In my tests with Visual Studio 2017 64 bits, these errors can be solved by re-run `qmake` and `rebuild` the 64 bits application on Qt Creator.

Comment: Thankyou for your time. I have installed a VS sample application source that works when compiled in 32 bit mode. I have  However I still have not solved my problem for Qt.

Comment: I have made progress: I can interface to DLL's made with MSVC via QLibrary which allows loading at any time the programmer chooses. I have not been able to make it work with the scanner's library (bad declaration of functions?) but I have been able to make a "bridge" DLL that calls the scanner library, providing I put the scanner's DLL in the same directory as my Qt Executable. A nice way to spend a weekend.